# error using Type: Function versus Type:any

Tags: typescript, dictionary, syntax

For learning purposes, I created a simple map2 function that is passed an increment function. However, I cannot explicitly pass it as Function (applyFun must be passed as type any).

```
function increment(val:number):number {
    return ++val;
}

function map2(arr: number[], applyFun: any): number[] {

    const temp: number[] = arr.map(applyFun); 
    return temp;

}


let testArray = [1,2,3];
testArray= map2(testArray,increment);
console.log(testArray);
```

I have a question as to why after changing from:

```
function map2(arr: number[], applyFun: any): number[]
```

to:

```
function map2(arr: number[], applyFun: Function): number[]
```

results in an error:

```
error TS2345: Argument of type 'Function' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: number, index: number, array: number[]) => number'.
  Type 'Function' provides no match for the signature '(value: number, index: number, array: number[]): number'.

9     const temp: number[] = arr.map(applyFun);
                                     ~~~~~~~~


Found 1 error.
```

I am asking as a general question, how can I be more explicit here without resorting to using :any ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be more specific with the function signature.

```
function increment(val:number):number {
    return ++val;
}

function map2(arr: number[], applyFun: (val: number) => number): number[] {

    const temp: number[] = arr.map(applyFun); 
    return temp;

}


let testArray = [1,2,3];
testArray= map2(testArray,increment);
console.log(testArray);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=15&ssc=24&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDSAnApgW3WKAKANwEMAbALjBEwCN1UBKCq21RAbwFgAoRXxDKCFRIA1COIkA3NwC+3bqEiwEiTEQAOAJjxFUqMoko06AbQC6AGkQb1JAJ4AxcAcKkDRlvUQBeAHyHmOkYA41RzdnkePggEAGcoRCgsdXdAsLMfaz0AOjV1HXVbR3B6SURuPn50QWFE5OkuWUjuEmq6+IBBPSI7TJMARgtNCwBmMwakzu67b1UNbUmoLtQeixQIDGxcUu4YsFi4VuySOABzPEXlntKgA)

Comment: Follow-up question: Why can't i add {} around number in this line so that it looks like this:    
  

`function map2(arr: number[], applyFun: (val:number)=> {number}): number[]` ?

Comment: @MM. which number ? Sorry, the question it's not clear to me

Comment: In line 5 of your answer, you added "applyFun: (val: number) => number" as the second parameter of the map2 function. Why is it incorrect to write "applyFun: (val: number) => {number}" instead?

Comment: I think I answered my question: `If your function is in a block, you must also use the explicit return statement:`

Comment: @MM. ` (val: number) => number` is a type, it's a function signature, the part after `=>` is the return type in this case `number`. `{ number }` would not really be valid syntax